# cabal v2-install --lib has dependency conflicts whereas v2-build succeeds on NixOS for HStringTemplate

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix, nixos, hstringtemplate

I am trying to solve a potential bug (removal of backslashes in templates) of the unmaintained [HStringTemplate](https://hub.darcs.net/sterlingclover/hstringtemplate). I am using [modified fork](https://github.com/nilehmann/hstringtemplate) of the project, hoping to be able to eventually submit it to hackage.

In order to use the library within my project I added the dependency to my cabal project:

```
executable texgeneration
    -- Import common warning flags.
    import:           warnings

    -- .hs or .lhs file containing the Main module.
    main-is:          Main.hs

    build-depends:    
        base ^>=4.16.3.0,
        HStringTemplate ^>=0.9.0,
```

Note that I increased the version number of `HStringTemplate` to `0.9.0` to ensure my version and not a different one from hackage will be used.

I cloned the `HStringTemplate` project from github, modified the cabal project version and ran `cabal v2-build --constraint "directory == 1.3.8.1"`, followed by `cabal v2-freeze`. These commands worked fine, but a subsequent execution of **`cabal v2-install --lib all`** to make `HStringTemplate 0.9.0` available to my project failed with:

```
Wrote tarball sdist to
/home/me/Documents/repos/texgeneration/hstringtemplate/dist-newstyle/sdist/HStringTemplate-0.9.0.tar.gz
Resolving dependencies...
Error: cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] next goal: directory (user goal)
[__0] rejecting: directory-1.3.8.1, directory-1.3.8.0 (constraint from user
target requires ==1.3.7.1)
[__0] rejecting: directory-1.3.7.1 (constraint from project config
/home/me/Documents/repos/texgeneration/hstringtemplate/cabal.project.freeze
requires ==1.3.8.1)
[__0] rejecting: directory-1.3.7.0, directory-1.3.6.2/installed-1.3.6.2,
directory-1.3.6.2, directory-1.3.6.1, directory-1.3.6.0, directory-1.3.5.0,
directory-1.3.4.0, directory-1.3.3.2, directory-1.3.3.1, directory-1.3.3.0,
directory-1.3.2.2, directory-1.3.2.1, directory-1.3.2.0, directory-1.3.1.5,
directory-1.3.1.4, directory-1.3.1.3, directory-1.3.1.2, directory-1.3.1.1,
directory-1.3.1.0, directory-1.3.0.2, directory-1.3.0.1, directory-1.3.0.0,
directory-1.2.7.1, directory-1.2.7.0, directory-1.2.6.3, directory-1.2.6.2,
directory-1.2.5.1, directory-1.2.5.0, directory-1.2.4.0, directory-1.2.3.1,
directory-1.2.3.0, directory-1.2.2.1, directory-1.2.2.0, directory-1.2.1.0,
directory-1.2.0.1, directory-1.2.0.0, directory-1.1.0.2, directory-1.1.0.1,
directory-1.1.0.0, directory-1.0.1.2, directory-1.0.1.1, directory-1.0.1.0,
directory-1.0.0.3, directory-1.0.0.0, directory-1.2.6.1 (constraint from user
target requires ==1.3.7.1)
[__0] fail (backjumping, conflict set: directory)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: directory
```

I failed to find more information on how this could be debugged (e.g. understanding the dependency tree) and I wonder why `cabal v2-build` worked fine.

Comment: You only mention `cabal install --lib` in your title, but not in your question itself. Is that intended?

Comment: @Noughtmare thanks, fixed now. I am trying to use `cabal v2-install --lib` to make the library available locally for use by other projects.

Comment: I think the issue is that you previously ran a `cabal install --lib` command which picked `directory-1.3.7.1`. After a dependency version is installed once with `--lib` then you can never change it in the future. This is why you should avoid `--lib`.

Comment: @Noughtmare Ok, I deleted ghc ([`sudo nix-store --query --referrers /nix/store/d....-ghc-9.2.6 | xargs nix-store --delete`](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nix-store-cannot-remove-a-package/20770/11)) and the [`~/.ghc`](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6394#issuecomment-670954957) folder. Then `cabal v2-install --lib` (I think I need `--lib` or what's the alternative?) succeeded, but not `cabal v2-build` in the project where I include `HStringTemplate` (`directory-1.3.8.1, directory-1.3.8.0 (constraint from user target requires ==1.3.7.1)`. I also tried deleting the `~/.cabal` folder.

Comment: The recommended alternative is to [use a `cabal.project` file and specify your fork as a `source-repository-package`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-project.html#specifying-packages-from-remote-version-control-locations)